# XML to Xcode Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xml-parsing

I am parsing data from a XML file to my app in Xcode. it is parsing but first value is not showing in `UITableView` please help. let me show you my code.

ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/mycategories.xml"]];
    xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        xmlStringFileObject =[[XMLStringFile alloc]init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSLog(@"node content = %@",nodecontent);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmltitle=nodecontent;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmllink=nodecontent;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        [rssOutputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];
        xmlStringFileObject = nil;
    }
    nodecontent=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}
```

And my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
      <item><title>Eggs</title>
      <link>http://url/category.php?cat_id=15</link></item>
      <item><title>Bakery</title>
      <link>http://url/category.php?cat_id=15</link></item>
      <item><title>Bread</title>
      <link>http://url/category.php?cat_id=16</link></item>
      <item><title>Cakes, Pies Patisserie</title>
      <link>http://url/category.php?cat_id=17</link></item>
      <item><title>Specialty Breads</title>
      <link>http://url/category.php?cat_id=119</link></item>
</data>
```

now in output i can see all the entries but not first one's title "Eggs"

Comment: can you give me ur URL

Comment: put a breakpoint, I think you initialize later nodecontent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't allocate your *nodecontent* in *didEndElement* method : you will have an allocated object when your parsing is over.

Try this way :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/mycategories.xml"]];
    xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        xmlStringFileObject =[[XMLStringFile alloc]init];
    } else {
     nodecontent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        [rssOutputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];
        xmlStringFileObject = nil;
    } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmltitle= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmllink= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because you are initialise `nodecontent` string in `NSXMLParser` delegate method `didEndElement:`.

So what happen when parser found first object it will initialise `nodecontent` string and first object will not append to string because it is not initialise that time but for second object and all remains will be added in `nodecontent` as it is initialise after first call.

So better to alloc init `nodecontent` in `viewDidLoad()` method, before parsing XML file.

Remove line `nodecontent=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];` from `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    nodecontent=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/mycategories.xml"]];
    xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmltitle=nodecontent;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xmllink=nodecontent;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        [rssOutputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];
        xmlStringFileObject = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i didnt noticed that. :)